# storing virtual box VMs in multiple partitions in CentOS

Tags: linux, virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine, centos

A CentOS 7 server has Virtual Box installed, and the default location of the Virtual Machines is in `/root/VirtualBox VMs`.  **Is there a way that I can put each virtual machine in a separate partition?**  I will eventually want to separately encrypt each partition, but for now, I just want each VM in its own partition, so that `vm1` is in `/custompartition1`, and `vm2` is in `/custompartition2`, and so on.  The partitions have already been created, but **how can I set things up so that each virtual machine is located in its own separate partition?**

---

**CLARIFICATION:**

---

In hopes of clarifying @MohammadMoeni's suggestion, I am clarifying my request as follows:

I want to remove `vm1` from `/root/VirtualBox VMs/vm1`, and instead locate it at `/custompartition1/vms/vm1`.  I also want to remove `vm2` from `/root/VirtualBox VMs/vm2` and instead locate it at `/custompartition2/vms/vm2`.

**What specific steps do I take to set up VirtualBox so that it will run `vm1` from `/custompartition1/vms/vm1` (and so on for `vm2`)?**  And how can this be set up in a way that will enable me to later encrypt the partition?

Note that the server has a minimal install of CentOS 7, so I am using `VBoxManage` at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your folder virtual machine to another folder andthe open it on virtualbox
In virtual machines hdd is many important you can make a virtual machine hdd and folder customize in another path (partition)

Comment: Thank you, but your response is not clear.  I have added clarification to the end of my **OP**.  Can you please elaborate with the specific steps that need to be taken to accomplish the specific results that I have clarified in my **OP**?

Comment: You should have a folder called VirtualBox VMs. This folder has all of your guests in them (if they were created with version => 4.*) including the snapshots.
You can copy this folder to the new location and remove them from the VirtualBox main manager (without deleting them)
Then use the add feature to add them back one at a time. (select the *.vbox file)
You should then open the preference section in the VirtualBox main manager and change the default location to the new place.

Be sure to backup the VirtualBox.xml file before you start just in case you make a mistake.
Once this is all workin

Comment: Thank you.  Remember this is a terminal-only installation of CentOS 7, so there is no GUI.  The first test virtual machine (`vm1`) is in a zip file.  I can move the zip file to `/custompartition1/vms/vm1` and unzip it, but then what commands do I type in the terminal to get `VBoxManage` to register and load the new `vm1`?  Also, keep in mind that each virtual machine will be in its own partition.  If I understand you correctly, you are saying to move the entire `/VirtualBox VMs` directory, which would limit me to only one other partition instead of n-partitions.